# Replace C++ function with Regular Expression

Tags: c++, regex

I would like to convert the following C++ method to a regular expression match/replace string pair. Is it possible to do this in a single pass, i.e. with a single call to a regex replace method? (such as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) one)

```
std::string f(std::string value)
{
    if (value.length() < 3)
    {
        value = std::string("0") + value;
    }

    value = value.substr(0, value.length() - 2) + std::string(".") + value.substr(value.length() - 2, 2);

    return value;
}
```

The input is a string of one or more digits.
Some examples:

```
f("1234") = "12.34"
f("123") = "1.23"
f("12") = "0.12"
f("1") = ".01"
```

The only way I've been able to achieve this so far is by using 2 steps:
1. Apply a prefix of "00" to the input string.
2. Use the following regex match/replace pair: 
Match: (0*)(\d+)(\d{2})
Replace: $2.$3

My question is, can this be done in a single "pass" by only calling the Regex replace method once and without prepending anything to the string beforehand.
I believe this isn't possible with a single expression/replacement, but I'd just like someone to confirm that (or otherwise provide a solution :) ).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is the current method you have to slow (you have measured I hope)? What makes you think using a regular expression query/replace method would be better?

Comment: please add input and output.

Comment: It looks to me that this method is prefixing with a 0 if the string has less than 3 characters, or inserting a . before the last 2 characters if the length is greater than 2. Using regular expressions for this looks over complicated to me.

Comment: @Joachim - I want to allow the user control of the formatting while keeping the current behavior as default. My thought was to make this configurable by allowing the user to specify a regex match/replace pair, but I'm not sure that would be sufficient to satisfy this case. No performance considerations whatsoever.

Comment: @Mike In this case, it might be easier to use this a default formatting when user doesn't specify a custom format. --- OTOH, it shows that regexp might be the wrong tool. If you can't find the magic expression, how should your users?

Comment: Good point Peter. I may have to consider doing something else. My knowledge on regular expressions is limited to say the least, so I wanted to make sure I'm not overlooking a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. (Change a bit again) x3.

```
string a_="123456";
a_="14";
a_="9";

string a = regex_replace(a_,regex("(.*)(.{2})|()"),string("$1.$2."));
//a = regex_replace(regex_replace(a,regex("^"),string("00$1$2")),regex("(.+)(.{2})"),string("$1.$2"));
//a = regex_replace("00"+a,regex("(.+)(.{2})"),string("$1.$2"));
float i=atof(a.c_str());
if(!(i))//just go here for 0-9 
{
    i=atof((string("0.0")+a_).c_str());
}
cout<<i<<endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: The intent was to only use regex_replace, but in this case you are also modifying the string by other means...

Comment: If you mean regex_str by modifying the string , the solution can be take reverse of string 'a' but it's also modifying too...

Comment: That's using regex_replace twice, so again it does not answer the question :)

Comment: change a bit again if you say "00"+a is modifying i probably cant go more far that is my last shot:D.

Comment: That is the same as my original solution of using a prefix of "00" for the input string.
Thanks for the effort though! :)

Comment: No problem but i really love challanges even if i am not that good about subjects and i update one more time my answer.